# Loop error too much output unterminated loop

Tags: java, loops

I need to write a Java program that takes in a line of text as input, and outputs that line of text in reverse. The program repeats, ending when the user enters "Done", "done", or "d" for the line of text.

For example, if the input is:

```
Hello there
Hey
done
```

The output should be:

```
ereht olleH
yeH
enod
```

Here is my current code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput;
        int numCharacter;  
        int i;
  
        userInput = scnr.nextLine();
  
  
        while((!userInput.equals("Done")) && 
        (!userInput.equals("done")) && (!userInput.equals("d"))) 
        {
            numCharacter=userInput.length();
            for (i=numCharacter; i>0; --i) 
            {
                System.out.print(userInput.charAt(i-1));
            }
        }
  
        System.out.println();
    userInput = scnr.nextLine();      
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Program generated too much output.
Output restricted to 50000 characters.

Check program for any unterminated loops generating output.
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not share core as images but rather copy/paste the code.

Comment: Look at your `while` loop. Notice you check against some user input? Great! Now, look at where you read more user input. That does not appear to be in the `while` loop. Have you tested your own program locally?

Comment: I tried your code, and it does indeed never end. Have you tried it yourself? Your while-loop does not try to read more input from the user, it loops forever on the first input the user puts in.

Comment: If you are not familiar with debugging, or not familiar with using a debugger, this is a good program to practice with.  Using the debugger, answer this: What happens if, for example, the user types "foo" as the input?

Comment: I dont know what testing it locally means haha

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you read up some on the scanner class in Java.
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.

Some things thing to take into consideration.

First you probably want that nextLine in the loop :). Currently your not grabbing new user input. Start there

You need to call nextLine each time you have a new string that you have typed into the terminal and want to enter. This could be done by checking in a while loop if the user presses the enter key.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The *short* answer is you're aren't reading more `userInput` after the first time you read `userInput`. You need to do that or your program will indeed loop forever.

```
userInput = scnr.nextLine();

while ((!userInput.equals("Done"))
            && (!userInput.equals("done"))
            && (!userInput.equals("d"))) {
    numCharacter = userInput.length();
    for (i = numCharacter; i > 0; --i) {
        System.out.print(userInput.charAt(i - 1));
    }
    System.out.println();
    // You forgot
    userInput = scnr.nextLine(); // <-- read userInput
}
```

However, I would *simplify* the code. Start by writing a method to test if a `String` matches the definition for done. Like,

```
private static boolean isDone(String s) {
    return "Done".equals(s) || "done".equals(s) || "d".equals(s);
}
```

Next, Java provides `StringBuilder` for creating *mutable* sequences of characters (**and** it has a `reverse()` method). So, `main` could be as simple as

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = scnr.nextLine();

while (!isDone(userInput)) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(userInput).reverse();
    System.out.println(sb);
    userInput = scnr.nextLine(); // Still need this
}
```

Finally, we can use side-effect(s) of assignment to simplify to the form you perhaps thought you had

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput;
while (!isDone(userInput = scnr.nextLine())) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(userInput).reverse();
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

And now we don't need to duplicate `userInput = scnr.nextLine()`

Comment: I added the last user input and am still getting the same error. I also tried entering what you posted and I got a ton of errors. It is in ZyBooks. I dont know if that makes a difference or not. Keeping my original code, do you have a suggestion on how to get it to read the next user input? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Looking at your edit to your question, you still aren't reading `userInput` **in** the `while` loop. Look at the very first code section in my answer. That is your code. Fixed.